# How to parse file to commands in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I'm trying to achieve some goal here and while I do know partials steps, I am not successful in putting it all together. I'm looking for an inline command for single usage on multiple hosts. Let's have SW repository file organized like this:

```
# comments
PROD_NAME:INSTALL_DIR:OPTIONS
PROD_NAME:INSTALL_DIR:OPTIONS
PROD_NAME:INSTALL_DIR:OPTIONS
```

Now, let's say we want to process the file and do some copy action on every one of the products. So, I can pipe `grep` getting rid of comment lines into `while do` cycle, where I use `awk` to break down each line to product name and it's path and complete it into copy commands. And that's too much of nesting for my skill level, I'm afraid. Anyone who'd care to share?

Comment: Provide details of script's expected output . What would the script do? Be specific to get specific answers . You can also make your own research wigh google like "bash read lines from file" or "bash split lines from file"

Comment: Sorry. The script would run e.g. `cp INSTALL_DIR INSTALL_DIR/PROD_NAME` (real life will be more complex but this is ok) for each uncommented line in the repository file.

Comment: While this works `echo $line | gawk -F'[:]' '{ print $2 }'`, this doesn't: `while read line ; do  echo $line | gawk -F'[:]' '{ print $2 }'; done | grep [#] /var/opt/repo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a `bash` loop to do the same

```
$ while IFS=: read -r p i o; 
  do echo "cp $o $p $i"; 
  done < <(grep -v '^#' file)

cp OPTIONS PROD_NAME INSTALL_DIR
cp OPTIONS PROD_NAME INSTALL_DIR
cp OPTIONS PROD_NAME INSTALL_DIR
```

remove echo to run as given.

Comment: Yeah, I got somewhere here with `while read line ; do `echo $line | gawk -F'[#]' '{ print $3 }'`; done | grep [#] /var/opt/repo` but I still can't figure the missing part, how to read and break the line to parts, which works for me by alone but not in the cycle.

Comment: your script doesn't match the input file you posted.  Did you test with the input file you posted?  The field delimiter is `:` not `#`.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't, you're right. I got kinda confused by trying various options and posted different command. But I realized your example would work and does exactly the example I was asking even without `awk`, thanks, it's quick and elegant. I will try to alter it to complete the complex commands inside.

Answer (score 0):

Comments can be removed by

```
grep -v '^#'
```

For awk you have to specify the field delimiter:

```
awk -f: '{print $1, $2, $3}'
```

In order to craft copy commands you have to pipe the result to a shell.

```
echo -e '# comments\nNAME:DIR:OPT' |
grep -v '^#' |
awk -F: '{print "cp", $3, $2, $1}' |
sh
```

Even better: read a book.

Or this:

- http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting

Comment: Thank you, as above. I know these partials steps but can't figure out how to put it together.